# Converting XY coordinates to lat, lon in the Iberian peninsula

Tags: coordinates, convert, latitude-longitude, pyproj, xy

I have been looking for a way to convert XY coordinates (from a coordinate system based on ETRS89) to latitude and longitude coordinates.

So far I have this function:

```py
from pyproj import Proj, transform

def utm_to_lon_lat(easting, northing):
    
    """
    ETRS89 to latitude, longitude converter
    :param easting: Easting coordinates array
    :return: latitude, longitude arrays
    """
    
    n = len(easting)
    latitude = np.zeros(n)
    longitude = np.zeros(n)

    inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
    outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

    for i in range(n):
        if not np.isnan(easting[i] + northing[i]):
            latitude[i], longitude[i] = transform(inProj, outProj, easting[i], northing[i])
            print(easting[i], northing[i], '->', latitude[i], longitude[i])

    return latitude, longitude
```

However, it is not working. The error is that not all the points fall into what I know is the area of the domain, The Iberian peninsula. My guess is that I got the projections wrong, is no it?

Comment: Please specify "it is not working". Does it return an error? Is there no output?

Comment: epsg:3857 is not ETRS89 - it's web mercator.  Furthermore your function states UTM as the source instead?  Which is it?

Comment: @Erik, Sorry, the error is that not all the points fall into what I know is the area of domain; The iberian peninsula.

Comment: @JimT, How can I know which projection is which?

Comment: EPSG:4326 is not ETRS:89 either; closest ETRS:89 CRS match to EPSG:4326 would be EPSG:4258 both are lat/long

Comment: There are a number of projected CRS that could be used ~ https://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=lastQuery&title=&reportDetail=long&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=Iberian%20CRS&r=16

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a few points, particularly one of those that is outside the area of domain? Spain usually uses ETRS89 UTM zones 29N, 30N, and 31N. If the data covers all of Spain, you might have all 3 zones and will have to figure out which zone a coordinate pair is in.

Comment: @nmtoken could you please clarify which is which? From the synthax of your comment I cannot infer what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The first step I would recommend would be to find the projection that best matches your area of interest. You can do this with the [`pyproj.CRS`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/crs/crs.html#crs) class.

Note: the bounds are in this order -> (min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat)

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> CRS("EPSG:25829")
<Projected CRS: EPSG:25829>
Name: ETRS89 / UTM zone 29N
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: Europe - 12°W to 6°W and ETRS89 by country
- bounds: (-12.0, 34.91, -6.0, 74.13)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: UTM zone 29N
- method: Transverse Mercator
Datum: European Terrestrial Reference System 1989
- Ellipsoid: GRS 1980
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich

>>> CRS("EPSG:25829").area_of_use.bounds
(-12.0, 34.91, -6.0, 74.13)
>>> CRS("EPSG:25830").area_of_use.bounds
(-6.0, 35.26, 0.0, 80.53)
>>> CRS("EPSG:25831").area_of_use.bounds
(0.0, 37.0, 6.01, 82.41)
>>> CRS("EPSG:25832").area_of_use.bounds
(6.0, 38.76, 12.0, 83.92)
```

Based on the point: latitude: 40.4369792, longitude: -11.6973331
The best projection looks to be `EPSG:25829`

Then, you can perform the transformation from latlon (EPSG:4326) to ETRS89 UTM (EPSG:25829) and back again like so:

```py
>>> trans = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:25829")
>>> trans.transform(40.4369792,-11.6973331)
(271217.25732365483, 4479753.803288419)
>>> trans = Transformer.from_crs("EPSG:25829", "EPSG:4326")
>>> trans.transform(271217.25732365483, 4479753.803288419)
(40.43697919999999, -11.6973331)
```

Note: axis order can be tricky. If you prefer lon lat (traditional xy order) I would look into using the `always_xy` option on the [Transformer](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html).